# how to handle null pointer exception while creating on demand singleton object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, singleton

---

Hi there ,

I am facing an issue with creating only three singleton object.
if the number of object increase after 3. Program throwing `NullPointerException`.

so I am trying to put the code inside try and catch but getting error mentioned below

> Syntax error on tokens, ConstructorHeaderName expected instead

```
try {
    public static Singleton getInstance() { 
        if (Singleton.counter < 3) {
            System.out.println("counter no"+ Singleton.counter);         
            single_instance = new Singleton();  
            return single_instance;
        } else

        return null;
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Note that you are not supposed to create multiple instances of a singleton object.

Comment: A) Please read [mcve] and enhance your question according. Do you get a runtime exception or a **syntax error** ?? B) The idea of a singleton is to have exactly one object. Not 0, not 3. Whatever you intend to do, it is not a singleton!

Comment: And hint: you never ever catch NPEs. You FIX them by preventing them from happening. Nothing in your code should throw an NPE .... If `new Singleton()` does throw up, then you got a BUG that you have to fix!

Comment: As the name **Singleton** already says, it is a class that is supposed to have only one **single instance**.

Comment: Do not use `_` in names in Java. use camel case

Comment: The try/catch would have to be inside the method, not around it.

Comment: `try` statement should be inside method.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a syntax error. `try`, `catch` should be inside the method body like this:

```
public static Singleton getInstance() {
    try { 
        if (Singleton.counter < 3) {
            System.out.println("counter no"+ Singleton.counter);         
            single_instance = new Singleton();  
            return single_instance;
        } else
            return null;
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole code is one big error. That one detail really doesn't cut it.

Comment: This piece of code won't throw an NPE anyway, so the whole `try` is kinda redundant to begin with. It's only later when the returned `null` is used that the NPE is thrown.

Comment: actually i tired that also ........getting new error on main Class , i have declared singleton and main class in same file ,,so at first i did put try inside method  getting this error  ...."The method main cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type"

Comment: what is the error means ,,do i need to seperate both the class on seperate files and import one class to another ?.....how i can avoid this error or prevent it

Comment: You can have the main method in the same singleton class. I think this error is something else. So, please post a separate question with your complete code and complete error message. For better help post [mcve].